# Do Rails enums as strings convert to methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have the following:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum speed: { "too fast": 0, "too slow": 1 }
end
```

Does Rails provide methods out of these?

For example:

```
car.too_fast?
```

Comment: If you look at the implementation it just calls `.to_s` on the labels so this is a pretty horrible idea. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/404ad9e8acf8ab45ae2314050131a00e57e63b40/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L151

Comment: @max Thanks for clearing that up for me! Removed

Answer (score 4):

> Does Rails provide methods out of these?

**Yes**, ActiveRecord::Enum just [iterates across the hash and defines methods based on the keys](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/404ad9e8acf8ab45ae2314050131a00e57e63b40/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L158). But it won't protect you from your own foolishness and *snake_case* the keys.

```
irb(main):001:0> Car.too_fast
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `too_fast' for Car (call 'Car.connection' to establish a connection):Class)
Did you mean?  too fast
irb(main):002:0> Car.send("too fast")
  Car Load (6.1ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."speed" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["speed", 0], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

You should note here that when you use [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method) you can actually create methods with names that would be syntactically invalid if you used the `def` keyword. Like methods with spaces in them. But you can't actually call the methods without using `send` or `call` since parens are optional in Ruby.

**TLDR;** don't do this. There is no valid reason why you won't do it in the first place as enums should represent internal state flags for your models and not the actual user facing labels. And anybody who later digs up this code with methods with spaces in them will hate you with a passion. And this will also most likely result in an endless supply of bugs.

Enum keys should be symbols which comply to the [community naming conventions for methods and variables](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars).